# C++ Function with empty body vs function with no body

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to understand the difference between having no body and having an empty body, as in these two functions:

```
void draw() const override; 
void rotate(int angle) override {}
```

The complete code is shown below, where `Shape` is an interface and `Circle` an implementation of that interface.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class Point {
    public:
        double x() {
            return x_coordinate;
        }
        double y() {
            return y_coordinate;
        }
    private:
        double x_coordinate, y_coordinate;
};

class Shape {
    public:
        virtual Point center() const =0;
        virtual void move(Point to) =0;
        virtual void draw() const =0;
        virtual void rotate(int angle) =0;
        virtual ~Shape() {}
};

class Circle: public Shape {
    public:
        Circle(Point p, int radius);
        Point center() {
            return c;
        }
        void move(Point to) {
            c = to;
        }
        void draw() const override; 
        void rotate(int angle) override {}
    private:
        Point c;    
        int r;
};
```

Comment: The first one is a declaration. The second one is a declaration and a definition.

Comment: you will notice a difference when you write a `main` and try to call the two methods

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Or possibly if you try to compile a program which just uses a constructor and destructor of `Circle` and does nothing else with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function declaration tells the compiler everything it needs to know to call a function. With that information the compiler can generate intermediate files such as "obj" files.

Once the code is compiled, the next step is to link it, during linking the linker has to put the actual location for the code into the final exe. This where the function definition comes in, if the linker can't find the function definition you will get an error.

You can seperate the function declaration from the definition which is common practice as it helps speed up compiling, makes files clear and easy to read, and a few other niceties.

So:

```
 void draw() const override;
```

Is a declaration, telling the compiler what it needs to call it, but there is not enough information to actually jump to the code (since there is no code at all).

```
void rotate(int angle) override {}
```

Is a both, a declaration and a definition. This gives the compiler enough info to call it, and the linker enough info to jump to the actual code. The "{}" has a little bit of implied code and would expand to something like:

```
void rotate(int angle) override {return;} // do nothing and return
```

With classes, things get a bit murkier, but these basic rules always apply to every function, whether they are templates, classes, or just plain old c style code.

Answer (score 2):

The `void draw() const override;` line is not a function *definition* at all, merely a *declaration*; the compiler (or, possibly, the linker) expects there to be an actual definition, including a (possibly empty) body, somewhere else in your code.

The `void rotate(int angle) override {}` line **is** a complete definition – of a function that actually does nothing. Once you provide a function 'body', you have provided a definition – even if that body is empty (as is your `{}`).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the first one `draw()` is just a prototype while the second one `rotate()` is a no-op (i.e., does nothing.) If you call the first function, it will not link (edit!), while a call to the second one will compile and link but just will not do anything.

Comment: It WILL compile. It will NOT link.

Comment: doh! yes fixed sorry.